# Render template context data referenced from hardcoded HTML in Django model

Tags: python, html, django, web, django-templates

I have a Django app which is a news service. I have a basic html page which renders a single article. Up until now, every article had a standard format, Image, Author, and text content. Now I am making an update to allow articles to have multiple images between various paragraphs of the article text.

Currently, my HTML page to render a single article gets its data injected via a context object which contains the following Article model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(default=now)
    image = models.ImageField(storage=MediaStorage(), default='')
    external_source = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    album = models.OneToOneField(Album, related_name='album', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Within the HTML template, I display the content with the following code

```
<p>
    {{ article.content|safe }}
</p>
```

Since I want to embed the album images within the text, I am attempting to put HTML code inside the content TextField like the following:

```
Some random article text followed by and image...
<img class="img-responsive single_article_image" src="{{album.image.url}}">
Some more random article text
```

The problem is that the src reference to album.image does not resolve from the injected context and no image is rendered. The reason why I cannot put the img class hard coded in the template is because then there is no way to display images between text paragraphs of the article.

Answer (score 0):

The object in context is `Article`, so you have to always start from it. As you did with rendering content:

```
{{ article.content|safe }}
```

you should do with rendering related `Album` object:

```
{{ article.album.image.url }}
```

Comment: I am passing in the album as its own key in the context, I wish this was the answer. For more insight, this is the error

```Not Found: /articles/introduction-to-secret-societies/{{album.masonic_irs_statue.image.url}}
```

Comment: @redtomato You need to share more error traceback, because it does not say, what exactly is missing.